# Autofetch behavior with firehose cursor, when SQL_SOPT_SS_CURSOR_OPTIONS option is set to SQL_CO_FIREHOSE_AF

Tags: odbc

On firehose cursor, when statement attribute `SQL_SOPT_SS_CURSOR_OPTIONS` is set to `SQL_CO_FIREHOSE_AF`, and the  statement is executed, observed different behavior for autofetch which are mentioned below:

1) When SQLExecute is called first time it does not autofetch.
2) When SQLExecute is called second time on the same stament handle, after closing cursor using `SQLFreestmt(hstmt, SQL_CLOSE)`, it  autofetch 1 row  with `SQLExecute`.

So what is the expected behavior, whether it  should  autofetch or not ?  This seems to be bug in SQL Native client drivers.

Also I didn't see documentation for `SQL_CO_FIREHOSE_AF` but it is listed in `sqlncli.h` ?

**code snippet with comments:**

```
    rc = SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt1, (UWORD) SQL_SOPT_SS_CURSOR_OPTIONS, (SQLPOINTER) SQL_CO_FIREHOSE_AF, 0);
    ...
    rc = SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt1, SQL_ATTR_ROW_ARRAY_SIZE, (SQLPOINTER)1, 0);   
 // Execute first statement
    rc = SQLExecute(hstmt1);  // it does not autofetch the data.
    ...

    rc = SQLFreeStmt(hstmt1, SQL_CLOSE);
    ...
    rc = SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt1, SQL_ATTR_ROW_ARRAY_SIZE, (SQLPOINTER)1, 0);   
 // Execute first statement
 rc = SQLExecute(hstmt1);  // it  autofetch 1 record.
```

Thanks,

Mukesh